# DXL - Cannot repopulate ListView

Tags: listview, ibm-doors

I'm writing a script that will display all modules within a folder and subfolder of the users' choice. I can populate my ListView dialog box element once, but I cannot seem to update the results or display new results when running the search on a different folder.

So far I've tried simply overriding the data in the exisiting rows and columns, but that just appends the information. I've also tried calling the `empty(listView)` method, as well as calling `realize(Main_Dialog)` after that as specified [here on the IBM DXL forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=928d940a-983e-4401-8c8c-2efebbcd024d&ps=25).

I can still update the information in the first column after using the `empty` method, as such I've tried deleting the other columns and re-adding them, this has the same result as the `empty() -> realize()` calls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by Mathias Mamsch on [the IBM Developer Forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ce8a4f3b-67d9-4e7c-83f9-6b8e0a4f0fa9&ps=25)

The `empty()` method was working, but I was not correctly setting the values of the list after emptying it with `void set(DBE listView, int item, int column, string value)`

Full explanation is on the forum (linked previously)